# Need to move two menu items to the right side of the header in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have created 6 pages for the website and added into my header, Now need to move last two pages to the right side of the header in my website. Please help me how to do that. Thank you

Comment: May i know why you downvoted for this question to correct my in future ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some menu inside of the header? 
If you, just you have to take id values for that specific items who contains the links to those page and edit directly in the section Add CSS styles from your WP editor, and put something like this:

```
      #btn_Id_*,
      #btn_Id_* {
       float: right !important;
      }
```

I hope this one help you.

Comment: Yes I am using Menu inside the header let me check

Comment: menu-item-1085 and menu-item-1086 i need to move both of these pages to the right so can i add menu-item-1085 alone in custom css or both i have to add

Comment: I have added below code in custom css field but it is not working my code

#menu-item-1085,#menu-item-1086{
 float: right !important;
}

Comment: Can you please help me it is not working as you mentioned

Comment: It's some crazy to do this in  that way, because it depend about the rules CSS around the menu and if we can't see those rules or at least the position of that menu in the DOM  I'll be don't so easy. But one things is sure, you can move those items using css rules and put it on the place that you want.

Comment: Yes can you please ping me in skype if you are free now. Thank you

Comment: My client is given me deadline so i am working without sleep today,